# Add information for each test in a test run that is run from a ADO pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

In our build-pipeline we are doing some automatic tests on a server. We are uploading the test report in a j-unit format to the pipeline. At the moment we have all the documentation about what every test does in a excel document inside of our repo. But I want to have the documentation about what each test is doing "inside of Azure".
I would prefer it to be available from where I click on the test result from a pipeline as shown below
[image]

Where should this documenation be placed? Is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[PublishTestResults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results)

```yaml
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    #testResultsFormat: 'JUnit' # Options: JUnit, NUnit, VSTest, xUnit, cTest
    #testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml' 
    #searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)' # Optional
    #mergeTestResults: false # Optional
    #failTaskOnFailedTests: false # Optional
    #testRunTitle: # Optional
    #buildPlatform: # Optional
    #buildConfiguration: # Optional
    #publishRunAttachments: true # Optional
```

In addition if you have Jacoco coverage reports

[PublishCodeCoverageResults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results)

```yaml
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'JaCoCo' # Available options: 'JaCoCo', 'Cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: 
    #pathToSources: # Optional
    #reportDirectory: # Optional
    #additionalCodeCoverageFiles: # Optional
    #failIfCoverageEmpty: false # Optional
```